# linkWithCredential throws provider-already-linked error when adding emaillink authentication to user with password authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a user that is authenticated using email/password. When I try to add emaillink authentication for the user using [`credentialWithLink`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#static-credentialwithlink) and [`linkWithCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#linkwithcredential), I get an error:

```
code: "auth/provider-already-linked"
message: "User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider."
```

The error message is telling me that I cannot add emaillink authentication for the user because the user is already authenticated with an email provider using password.

So what is the correct way to add emaillink authentication for an existing user with password authentication?

Here is what I tried that is throwing the "auth/provider-already-linked" error:

1. create user with email and password. send email verification

```js
const userCred = await firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

if (userCred) {
  const { user } = userCred;
  await user.sendEmailVerification());
}
```

2. verify email

```js
await firebase.auth().applyActionCode(actionCode)
await firebase.auth().currentUser.reload()
```

At this point, the user is signed in and `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` returns `['password']`.

```js
const signInMethods = await firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email)

if (signInMethods) {
  console.log(signInMethods) // returns ['password']
}
```

3. send signin link to email

```js
await firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
window.localStorage.setItem('emailForSignIn', email)
```

4. confirm signin link

```js
if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(href)) {
  let email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn')
  if (!email) {
    email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation')
  }
  const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink(
    email,
    window.location.href
  );
  firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('success linking with email link')
      window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Some error occurred.
      console.log('error linking with email link')
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Since I'm already signed in and linked with email provider, calling `firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink` is throwing the error.

So how can I add `emaillink` signin method for a user already authenticated with an email provider that just has `password` signin method? From the error message, I know I shouldn't use `credentialWithLink` and `linkWithCredential`. So what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to link an account created using E-Mail with another E-Mail. As the error says, "User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider.". That means an account can only have one email, google account, facebook, etc linked together.

If you want to a user to have multiple emails, then you might have to use a database.
[image]

If you use Firestore, then you can store the emails like this and when needed make a query like:

```
userRef.where("emails", "array-contains", "emailEnteredByUser");
```

PS: User can only use the primary email which they first used to create an account to login or signup.

**A workaround:** You can actually rely on [Email-Link Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) to allow users to login. When a user enters their email and click login, you can run a cloud function (or a function in  your own server) to generate a sign in link and then verify if user's document contains the email they have entered and use something like [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) to email them the sign in link.

**Edit:** OP assumed password and sign-in links are different auth providers. As mentioned in the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#next_steps):

> After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is
> created and linked to the credentials—that is, the user name and
> password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed
> in with.
> So you can still use email links if the user exists with email.

Comment: I don't want a user to have multiple emails. Email auth provider has 2 methods of sign in: password & emaillink. I want user with password sign in method to also have emaillink sign in method. And I don't think it is necessary to use Firestore. Firebase Auth should be sufficient.

Comment: @kimbaudi that's the same thing. Even if you have password auth setup, you can still use the sendSignInLink method. Email is same for password or link. If it was you had used link for login and wanted to add password then you would have to use the update password method. No linking is involved here.

Comment: I figured out the solution. use `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, href)`. That is all. No need for Firestore. No workaround. Just call `signInWithEmailLink`.

Comment: @kimbaudi I've updated the solution with correct links to docs. If the answer was helpful you can accept it so others know it is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to add emaillink to a user with email/password sign in.

TL/DR; use `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, href)`. don't use `credentialWithLink` and `linkWithCredential`

Steps 1 - 3 are correct, but I needed to change step 4 to use `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, href)` instead of `credentialWithLink` and `linkWithCredential`

Here is the correct step 4:

```js
if (firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(href)) {
  let email = window.localStorage.getItem('emailForSignIn')
  if (!email) {
    email = window.prompt('Please provide your email for confirmation')
  }

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailLink(email, href)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('success linking with email link')
      window.localStorage.removeItem('emailForSignIn')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Some error occurred.
      console.log('error signing in with email link')
      console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm having the oposite case. The user signs in with an email link then on the second step i want to add a password. any idea how to achieve this?